# Using sql-server datetime2 with TADOQuery.open

Tags: sql-server, delphi, ado, delphi-xe

I want to start using `datetime2` fields in SQL Server and I need to insert into the tables via ADO from Delphi XE5. I am using `TADOQuery.ExecSQL` to insert and everything works fine.

However most of my tables have identity columns, e.g.

```
id integer identity(1,1) not null
```

To save round-trips to the server, I usually use `Open` with two commands in the query text.

- The first command is the insert
- the second command is "select scope_identity() as scope_id"

so I can retrieve the newly inserted **id** in the same round-trip.

This has worked for all my tables, but not now when I add `datetime2` or `time` column - I get the error:

> Project "Foo.exe raised exception class EOleException with message 'Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string".

I am using SQL Server 2008 if that matters. Does anyone know what might be the problem?

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that `datetime2` does not come back to ADO clients using the SQLOLEDB provider as the correct ADO data type ([adDBTimestamp](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms675318%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)):

> **adDBTimeStamp**  (135)
>
> Indicates a date/time stamp (yyyymmddhhmmss plus a fraction in billionths) (DBTYPE_DBTIMESTAMP).

Instead it comes back as a unicode string ([adVarWChar](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms675318%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)):

> **adVarWChar**  (202)
>
> Indicates a null-terminated Unicode character string.

- `2016-11-03 12:06:01.0000000`

### SQL Server Native Client (SQLNCLI)

You *could* try switching to one of the *"native"* OLEDB providers (e.g. SQLNCLI, SQLNCLI10, SQLNCLI11). The problem with those is that:

- the SQL Server Native client doesn't come with the operating system (you have to install it yourself on client PCs)
- [the SQL Server Native Client is derpricated](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh967418.aspx)
- the SQLNCLI provider exposes XML columns as an unsupported ADO DataTypeEnum value (141, DBTYPE_XML)
- the SQLNCLI provider exposes TIME columns as an unsupported ADO DataTypeEnum value (145)
- the SQLNCLI provider exposes UDT columns as an unsupported ADO DataTypeEnum value (132)

You can use the [`DataTypeCompatibility=80`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms130978.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) option in your connection string to cause XML columns to return as `adLongVarWChar` (as they do in SQLOLEDB), but then `datetime2`, `date`, and `time` return as strings

The problem with use `DataTypeCompatibility=80` is that there's a bug in the native client driver.  It mistakenly converts an SQL Server `DATE` column from **adDBDate** into **adVarWChar**:

```
 | SQL Server data type | SQLOLEDB        | SQLNCLI            | SQLNCLI w/DataTypeCompatibilyt=80 |
 |----------------------|-----------------|--------------------|-----------------------------------|
 | Xml                  | adLongVarWChar  | 141 (DBTYPE_XML)   | adLongVarChar                     |
 | datetime             | adDBTimeStamp   | adDBTimeStamp      | adDBTimeStamp                     |
 | datetime2            | adVarWChar      | adDBTimeStamp      | adVarWChar                        |
 | date                 | adVarWChar      | adDBDate           | adVarWChar                        |
 | time                 | adVarWChar      | 145 (unknown)      | adVarWChar                        |
 | UDT                  |                 | 132 (DBTYPE_UDT)   | adVarBinary (documented,untested) |
 | varchar(max)         | adLongVarChar   | adLongVarChar      | adLongVarChar                     |
 | nvarchar(max)        | adLongVarWChar  | adLongVarWChar     | adLongVarWChar                    |
 | varbinary(max)       | adLongVarBinary | adLongVarBinary    | adLongVarBinary                   |
 | timestamp            | adBinary        | adBinary           | adBinary                          |
```

This bug in the SQL Native Client Provider [was documented on MS Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/sql/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=316457). But the person from Microsoft, not understanding what he was told, closed it as **Won't fix**.

So, if you **really** want to use a `datetime2` from ADO, you will have to read it as a **string**, and parse it yourself.

## Bonus Reading

- [MSDN: Using ADO with SQL Server Native Client](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms130978.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: You're right. But where I find out that the string contains datetime? Note that you 're querying from a table that you don't know any thing about it.

Comment: @AminAlinezhad You're hoping to interrogate the *type* of the returned column, so that you can know it is in fact a date - and handle it as such. That's not going to happen as long as you use ADOdb. You'd have to use the OLEDB API directly, and that is something you **don't** want to get into. It is a ridiculously over-complicated OLEDB API (which is why ADO and ADO.net were created - as wrappers around OLEDB). You will just have to *know* the column *"is"* a datetime.