# Type mismatch when using DateValue() with a datetime2

Tags: vb6

Please see the simple code below:

```
DateValue(rs(0))
```

rs is a recordset and rs(0) is sometimes a datetime and sometimes a datetime2 from an SQL database depending on which database the app is connected to at the time.  If a datetime2 is passed to DateValue then I see a type mismatch error.  I could resolve the issue by ensuring that a datetime2 is always casted to a datetime in SQL like this: `select cast (created as datetime) from employee`.  However, I wandered if there was some way of getting round this in the VB6 code.

Comment: What does `rs(0).Type` show?

Comment: @GSerg, it shows: 3

Comment: That is `adInteger`. So that would probably be `CDate(rs(0))`. `CDate` would also be compatible with `adDBDate`.

Comment: @GSerg, so CDate should be ok to use with datetime and datetime2?

Comment: It would work with the numeric values, but actually I'm not certain if datetime2 results in useful integer values in a recordset. What `rs(0).Value` do you have for today ish dates?

Comment: @cserg, sorry I don't understand your question.

Comment: You have verified that `rs(0).Type` is 3. What is `rs(0).Value` when it's 3, and what actual date does it correspond to? According to https://stackoverflow.com/a/38664425/11683, you should be seeing 202 (`adVarWChar`), not 3.

Comment: Since your program should know which kind of DB it is connecting to, you could just process it two different ways based on that.

Comment: I think you already proposed the best/most robust solution in your question: (SQL) CAST it into a var type that VB6 can handle.