# timestamp column in MySQL detected as nvarchar in SqlServer via linked server

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, delphi, linked-server

I execute a query via SQL Server to retrieve data from a MySQL database like this:

```
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(MyLinkedServerNameToMySQL, 
                        'SELECT actor_id, first_name, last_Name, last_update 
                         FROM sakila.actor')
```

where the `last_update` column data type is `timestamp`.
After execution the query via Microsoft ADODataSet library and retrieving data in `DataSet`, the data type of `last_update` in `DataSet` is `nvarchar` while I expect `datetime`.
Can anyone explain why this issue occurs?

**UPDATE:**

here is my code:

```
unit GetDataFormMySQLU;

interface

procedure GetDataFromMySQL;

implementation

uses DB, ADODB, Variants;

procedure DoSomthingForBoolean(AValue: Variant);
begin
end;

procedure DoSomthingForDateTime(AValue: Variant);
begin
end;

procedure DoSomthingForNumber(AValue: Variant);
begin
end;

procedure DoSomthingForString(AValue: Variant);
begin
end;

procedure GetDataFromMySQL;
var
  LADOConn: TADOConnection;
  LDS: TADODataSet;
  i: Integer;
  LValue: Variant;
begin
  LADOConn := TADOConnection.Create(nil);
  try
    //:
    LDS := TADODataSet.Create(nil);
    try
      LDS.Connection := LADOConn;
      LDS.CommandText := 'SELECT * FROM ' +
                         'OPENQUERY(MyLinkedServerNameToMySQL, ' +
                            '''SELECT actor_id, first_name, last_Name, last_update ' +
                              'FROM sakila.actor'')';
      LDS.Open;
      while not LDS.Eof do
      begin
        for i := 0 to LDS.Fields.Count - 1 do
        begin
          LValue := LDS.Fields[i].Value;

          case LDS.Fields[i].DataType of
            ftBoolean: DoSomthingForBoolean(LValue);

            ftDate,
            ftTime,
            ftDateTime: DoSomthingForDateTime(LValue); (*this branch will not be invoked for
                                                         timestamp or datetime column of MySQL*)
            ftSmallint,
            ftInteger,
            ftWord,
            ftFloat,
            ftCurrency,
            ftBCD,
            ftAutoInc,
            ftLongWord,
            ftShortint,
            ftExtended,
            ftSingle: DoSomthingForNumber(LValue);

            else DoSomthingForString(LValue); (*actually timestamp and datetime data type of MySQL
                                                will be detected as ftWideString(nvarchar) and this
                                                branch will be invoked*)
          end;
        end;
        LDS.Next;
      end;
    finally
      LDS.Free;
    end;
  finally
    LADOConn.Free;
  end;
end;

end.
```

Comment: Maybe because of `TIMESTAMP Transact-SQL timestamp data type is different from the timestamp data type defined in the ISO standard. It has nothing to do with date and time. Timestamp is a synonym for rowversion.`

Comment: Can you try with a test table execute the same query but change `timestamp` to `datetime` and check if it produces the same error ?

Comment: How do you draw the conclusion that this column is `nvarchar` ?

Comment: @Luuk In my code I checked every columns data type

Comment: @ErgestBasha Yes. same issue is exists for datetime columns.

Comment: @AminAlinezhad, you checked the data type, but HOW did you check it?

Comment: BTW: the linked_server should not have quotes around it, see examples in  [OPENQUERY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openquery-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: @luuk @Luuk I checked data types with below code. it is Delphi syntax:     `for i := 0 to ADataSet.Fields.Count -1 do  if ADataSet.Fields[i].DataType  = ftDateTime then   DoSomething`

Comment: Please, add the code to your question (using [edit]).

Comment: Your problem was asked about earlier, see: [Using sql-server datetime2 with TADOQuery.open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38662438/using-sql-server-datetime2-with-tadoquery-open). The answer indicates that you might need to convert the string to whatever date-type you need in Delphi.

Comment: @Luuk You're right. but where I find out that the string contains datetime? Note that you 're querying from a table that you don't know any thing about it.

Comment: You do know something about the table `sakila.actor`. how would you be able to ask for the column `last_update` when you did know nothing about that table?

Comment: @Luuk In our use case we don't know anything about target table. we are working on a  BMPS's Discriminator and any DB or any Table can be identify by end user. So our codes for that must be dynamic. For example suppose that a user gives you a SQL and expected the result set in JSON format.  you don't know what columns user asked. how do you convert the SQL result set in to a JSON?

Comment: You could translate the unknown  fields (the `else` branch) to string, which might be correct in the example of `timestamp`. But these field can also have a datatype [BINARY](BINARY), which will en up in the `else` branch too, and you have to decide what to do with those kind of fields,,, ignore, or maybe base64-encode, or ...... ?

Answer (score 1):

With this in MySQL:

```
create table timestamps(t timestamp primary key);
insert into timestamps select current_timestamp;
insert into timestamps select current_timestamp;
insert into timestamps select current_timestamp;
insert into timestamps select current_timestamp;
insert into timestamps select current_timestamp;
```

You can get the data from Linked Server using:

```
SELECT *
FROM OPENQUERY(MYLINKEDSERVERNAMETOMYSQL,'SELECT t  FROM test.timestamps');
```

But also using:

```
SELECT t FROM  MYLINKEDSERVERNAMETOMYSQL.test..timestamps;
```

Above two statement produce results like:

```
t
---------------------------
2022-01-16 14:43:42.0000000
2022-01-16 14:43:43.0000000
2022-01-16 14:43:44.0000000
2022-01-16 14:43:45.0000000
2022-01-16 14:43:46.0000000
```

Using the [TYPE_NAME()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/type-name-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) produces an error:

```
SELECT t, TYPE_NAME(t) FROM  MYLINKEDSERVERNAMETOMYSQL.test..timestamps;
```

error:

```
Msg 206, Level 16, State 2, Line 18
Operand type clash: datetime2 is incompatible with int
```

Also:

```
SELECT t, SUBSTRING(t,1,7) FROM  MYLINKEDSERVERNAMETOMYSQL.test..timestamps;
```

Produces:

```
Msg 8116, Level 16, State 1, Line 25
Argument data type datetime2 is invalid for argument 1 of substring function.
```

Conclusion: The `timestamp` in MySQL is converted to a `datetime2` in MS-SQL.

EDIT:  [Charlieface](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14868997/charlieface) pointed me to the use of `SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY`, when doing this:

```
SELECT last_update, SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(CAST(last_update AS sql_variant), 'BaseType')
FROM OPENQUERY(MyLinkedServerNameToMySQL, 
                        'SELECT actor_id, first_name, last_Name, last_update 
                         FROM sakila.actor');
```

the response is:

```
last_update                 
--------------------------- ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2006-02-15 04:34:33.0000000 datetime2
2006-02-15 04:34:33.0000000 datetime2
2006-02-15 04:34:33.0000000 datetime2
2006-02-15 04:34:33.0000000 datetime2
2006-02-15 04:34:33.0000000 datetime2
...
```

NOTE: Above is with MySQL 8.0.27 and MS-SQL 15.0

Comment: Thanks to you. you find out in SSMS the `timestamp` of MySQL is recognize as `datetime2` of MS-SQL. But Microsoft ADO DataSet detected as `nvarchar`.